# Publish extension from Chrome web store to Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-apps-marketplace

Right now I have a Chrome Web Store extension written in JavaScript with JQuery and AngularJS code. I want to publish it also in GSuite Marketplace. Does it support such kind of applications?
As far as I see it has only Cards with simple HTML forms and Apps Script instead of the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[As per documentation](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/types) there are 2 kinds of add-ons:

1. Workspace add-on
2. Editor add-on

Editor add-on actually use HTML and CSS on a sidebar or dialogs as opposed to the card system. That may be what you are looking for.

Comment: But can they contain a jQuery/Angular? The Apps Script they support looks like some simplified and limited version of JavaScript.

Comment: @mirik Apps Script is executed on the server. You could think of it as a backend. Because of that, you don't have a `window` object. Other than that and a few other things (like workers or modules) it's has pretty much standard ES6. As for the Editor Add-ons you basically create a regular web page (HTML + CSS + JS) that gets iframed. Read about [how it is HTML interfaces work](https://developers.google.com/workspace/add-ons/concepts/html-interfaces).

Comment: I see, but it requires writing add-on from scratch. Is it possible to transfer existing Chrome Extension without writing any new code?

Comment: You'll probably have to write some code, but this could be minimal depending on your extension implementation and features.

Comment: This is bad. I thought it is possible just to republish existing Chrome extension to Marketplace without changing anything.